# Run script containing relative import within python package

Tags: python, package, python-import

How to run a script within the module when the module is not in my Python path?

Consider some imaginary package:

```
package/
     __init__.py
    main.py
    helper/  
        __init__.py
        script.py
    other/  
        __init__.py
        anotherscript.py
```

Say we want to run `script.py`. When the package is in my Python path, this does the job:

```
python -m package.helper.script
```

But what if it's not the case? Is there a way to tell python the location of the module? Something like

```
python -m /path_to_my_package/package.helper.script
```

(clearly, the above doesn't work)

I am looking for a solution that doesn't involve environmental variables.

`script.py` contains relative import, so the full path to `script.py` does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You could do this.  I assume this is from a cmd prompt or batch file?

```
SET PYTHONPATH=..\..\path\to\my\package;c:\other\path\thats\needed
python -m package.helper.script
```

You could also just pass the full path to your python file.  But that assumes your script is not expecting a particular environment path to be pre-set for it.

```
python -m path_to_my_package/package/helper/script.py
```

EDIT - If your script.py uses relative imports (and you don't want to change that), then there is no way to do it except getting that root path into the environment.  You can do this in your script if you want, instead of setting it in the cmd shell or batch file.  But it needs to get done somewhere.  Here's how you can set the environment path in your script:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'..\..\path\to\my\package')
import package.other.anotherscript
```

Comment: Well, the question is whether it is possible without modifying environmental variables. The second option is not the case because script.py uses relative imports from it's parent directory within the module.

Answer (score -1):

Your script.py should look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#here your python code

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #run you helper
```

Then make your script executable: `chmod +x script.py`.

Run ./path_to_my_package/package/helper/script.py from console.

Comment: It wouldn't work, as I use relative import within script.py. Is has to be run as a part of the module