# How to get system path to installed packages in Google Colab?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-import, google-colaboratory

I am trying to make my code installable from Github.

In a folder in my github, I have some scripts which have relative imports. I tried running the scripts but I get errors.

According to this SO question [Run script within python package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26811953/run-script-within-python-package)

> EDIT - If your script.py uses relative imports (and you don't want to
>   change that), then there is no way to do it except getting that root
>   path into the environment. You can do this in your script if you want,
>   instead of setting it in the cmd shell or batch file. But it needs to
>   get done somewhere. Here's how you can set the environment path in
>   your script:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'..\..\path\to\my\package')
import package.other.anotherscript
```

So now I'm trying to figure out what is the path to my installed Github, but I can't seem to find it.  It seems to have installed correctly, but it's just not there.

This is my Github

https://github.com/Santosh-Gupta/MedicalQA

These are my scripts, which have relative imports

https://github.com/Santosh-Gupta/MedicalQA/tree/master/Scripts

This is what I use to install my Github.

```
!pip install https://github.com/Santosh-Gupta/MedicalQA/archive/master.zip
```

I tried finding the package using

```
print(sys.path)
os.listdir('lib')
os.listdir('lib/python3.6')
os.listdir('lib/python3.6/site-packages')
```

Any other info for getting scripts and code with relative imports to work in python packages would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried using `pip show package_name` replace `package_name` with the  name of your package?

Comment: That worked. But now when I append the path, I'm still getting import errors. Will make a new stack overflow question

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `pip show <packagename>` to get path where package is stored

Comment: What if I used !apt-get install To install the package. Using !pip show .. returns a "no matching distribution" error. 
Trying to find the path to python-poppler

Comment: @Lawnio usually apt-get installs python packages to `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` I would start there if you are running python 3